# How to use expression list for mutate in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

I found that data masking that usually work in `dplyr` stop working when use together with `!!` operator.

Consider a simple example.

```r
trans <- list(
  a = rlang::expr(val),
  b = rlang::expr(val*2)
)

df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b"), val = 2:3)
```

Then, I would like to modify `val` column based on value from `name` using my list `trans`. Then, following code would not work.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(val = !!trans[[ name ]])
```

It appears that `name` was not found. The code above would work if the a normal variable were used in place of `name` column in the dataframe.

How should I modify the code to make it work as intended? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(val_res = eval(trans[[name]]))

#  name    val val_res
#  <chr> <int>   <dbl>
#1 a         2       2
#2 b         3       6
```